# use EntityFieldQuery to find user based on custom user profile field value

Tags: users

I have a profile field profile_full_name (title "full name") which I would like to use for searching users. Unfortunately below code throws an error. I've also tried

EntityFieldQueryException: Unknown field: profile_full_name in EntityFieldQuery->addFieldCondition()

```
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'user')
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->fieldCondition('profile_full_name', 'value', '%' . $name . '%', 'like')
      ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1)); // Run the query as user 1.
    $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Did you add the field through the UI? If so it'll be called 'field_profile_full_name'.

Comment: Unfortunately 'field_profile_full_name' did not work. In the profile_field table 'profile_full_name' is mentioned in the name column.

Comment: Ah ok, those "fields" aren't entity fields, the core profile module stores its data separately for some reason. You'll need to use a normal query, that data isn't compatible with EFQ

Comment: Do you use Profile2?